# Kohana Passing arrays by reference

Tags: php, reference, kohana

Using the kohana framework, if I do the folowing:

```
$this->view->bind('errors', $errors = array());
```

I get the PHP error
ErrorException "[ Strict ]: Only variables should be passed by reference"

If I do:

```
$this->view->bind('errors', $errors);
$errors = array();
```

I get no error.

Is it ok to avoid the error? Will this cause any problems?

Thanks!

Comment: Your second block of code doesn't help you out;  it writes over the values `bind` just inserted into the `$errors` array.  You may be able to just pass `null` as the second argument if you don't care about errors, or by not passing an argument entirely.

Comment: Yeah this was just an example. I just want to know if there are any negative effects of setting $errors as an array later in the code. I want to know the reason only variables should be passed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

In Kohana you can pass variables in 2 ways - using `set` or `bind`.
From [docs](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/mvc/views#variables-in-views):

> The only difference between set() and bind() is that bind() assigns
>   the variable by reference. If you bind() a variable before it has been
>   defined, the variable will be created with a value of NULL.

So `bind` is a little safer, if your variable is not always present in the view (like `errors` variable, which you would define in the post condition). Small example:

```
public function action_roadtrip()
{
    $post = $this->request->post();
    if (!empty($post))
    {
        try
        {
            // Do some ORM validation here
        }
        catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
        {
            $errors = $e->errors('');
        }
    }
    $view = View::factory('some_view_name')->bind('errors', $errors);
    $this->request->response = $view;
}
```

Note that even though you define the `errors` during POST, it's still safe to use it with GET in your view.

Another thing to note is that `bind` only supports variables (similar behaviour to [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function).
If you want to pass expressions, use `set`, just be aware of the difference between `bind`:

```
$this->view->set('errors', $errors = array());
```